# Best way to add custom / magic / flutter fields into RSS feed

Tags: custom-field, customization

Using Wordpress 3, creating write panels with Magic Fields, how do I add custom fields to my RSS feed?

For example, I have an 'image of the day' write panel, with a custom field for the photo credit. How can I include all that as part of my feed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this

```
function feed_magic_fields( $content ) {
  global $post, $id;

  if ( !is_feed() )
    return $content;

  // is feed
  $date = get('date_event');
  if( $date)
    $content .= $date

  return $content; 
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'feed_magic_fields' );
```

Comment: thanks for adding some code, that's basically what I meant no need to global $post, $id btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into your feed with the according filters and then add your stuff.

Basically [that codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_rss) suggests (and that's still valid, you find the feed templates inside  `/wp-includes/`, the files start with `feed-`) that you hook into `the_content` and you check with [`is_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) if you need to modify the content for the feed.

To save you some hassles, you can register your whole plugin to activate on the `do_feed_rss2` (or whichever you use) hook, so you do not need to check for `is_feed()`.

The contents of magic fields (custom fields to be precise) can be read out with existing functions, you find the documentation here: [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).